# Open the same serial port "Access to the port 'COM' is denied" in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, serial-port

I currently have a program that connected to the PLC of machine and each have a dedicated serial port that monitors a dedicated device.
I used port COM3 for monitoring L (Left) side and port COM5 for monitoring R (Right) side of PLC.
All works fine, with no conflicts.

But when I want to set COM3 for monitoring both of sides (L & R), I got an error info that says **"Access to the port 'COM3' is denied."**. I know this happened because port COM3 is already used by L (Left) sides.

I want to use if the else, like;

```
if Me.cPlc(i).PortOpen() Then 
     // Take the value and close
     Me.cPlc(i).PortClose(); 
End if
```

But I don't know how to do that. Does anyone know how to handle this problem ?
Thank you very much.

Here is the piece of code that is giving me trouble:

```
    'Open each port
    Dim length As Integer = Me.cPlc.Count - 1
    If length > -1 Then
        For i As Integer = 0 To length
            Me.cPlc(i).PortOpen()  // The error occurs on this line.
        Next
        Do
            'Read the device value from the PLC at the end of each port
            For i As Integer = 0 To length
                Me.cPlc(i).Scan()
            Next
        Loop Until Me.BgwPlc.CancellationPending = True
        'Close each port
        For i As Integer = 0 To length
            Me.cPlc(i).PortClose()
        Next
    End If
```

Comment: The SerialPort class has an IsOpen property that you can check

Comment: @F0r3v3r-A-N00b : Thank you for your response, did you mean this one System.IO.Ports.SerialPort ?

Comment: @F0r3v3r-A-N00b : I don't how to implement it ? Would you mind give me an example please ? Thank you in advance

Comment: Oh which serialport class are you using?

Comment: @F0r3v3r-A-N00b : I'm really sorry, this case was closed. I was misunderstanding about the flow of the code. It fixed by changing the code in form_shown. Thank you very much for your response and your help.